# Do unique constraints change the sort order of returned values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sorting

Does a UNIQUE constraint on a table alter the default sorting returned by a `SELECT` statement?

If so, why doesn't the PK's sorting override the UNIQUE constraint's sorting? My understanding is that a composite UNIQUE constraint creates a composite index for those columns, and thus a BTree. But wouldn't the PK be an additional BTree that takes precedence?

Of course, if I need things sorted I can `SELECT [columns] FROM table ORDER BY column`, but I'm not asking how to return sorted values.

---

#### Example:

If I have a MySQL table `a` defined like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
    `a_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `pixel_x` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `pixel_y` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`a_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `pixel_x_pixel_y_UNIQUE` (`pixel_x` , `pixel_y`)
)
```

And enter some data in this order:

```
a_id  pixel_x  pixel_y
====  =======  =======
1     548      553
2     2018     2035       <---  -- 2nd data entered
3     1319     1231
4     1998     651
```

When I `SELECT * FROM a`, I get the following:

```
a_id  pixel_x  pixel_y
====  =======  =======
1     548      553
3     1319     1231
4     1998     651
2     2018     2035       <---  -- 2nd data entered, but last in
                                -- the sort order because it's the
                                -- highest `pixel_x` value.
```

Comment: I've always read that if an order is needed you must use the `order by`, this thread seems to re-iterate that https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6051/what-is-the-default-order-of-records-for-a-select-statement-in-mysql

Comment: I agree, but I'm more asking about the internals of MySQL. Obviously there's *something* going on because the returned order changes. Without the constraint, values are returned sorted by PK.

Comment: The order is likely to be related to whichever key is used in executing the query. See what `EXPLAIN` says about how the query is processed.

Comment: The difference between a primary key and some other unique key is only relevant to the database user, they're equivalent to the DBMS itself. So there's no reason why it should prefer one over the other, and the choice is arbitrary.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, that is a good point regarding the lack of differences between a PK and an index. You're also correct: the order is related to which key is used. `EXPLAIN` on the table with a unique key is `type=index, key=x_y_unique, Extra=Using index` while the table with a PK only (no unique constraint) is `type=all, key=NULL, Extra=NULL`. Thanks for helping me understand things